# HTTP Error 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime Common solutions to this issue: The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App in .Net 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0

When I try to run basic ASP.NET Core 5 MVC project, I get this error:

```
HTTP Error 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime
Common solutions to this issue:
The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found.
Specific error detected by ANCM:
Error: An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (Microsoft.NETCore.App.deps.json) was not found: package: 'runtime.win-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.App', version: '5.0.17-servicing.22213.14' path: 'runtimes/win-x64/lib/net5.0/System.Linq.dll'
Troubleshooting steps:
Check the system event log for error messages
Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect
For more information visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2028526
```

I searched for solutions, I downloaded .NET 5 Hosting Bundle and still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your description,if you want to run  ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project,you have to installing [.net 6](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0)  instead of .net 5 Hosting Bundle

Comment: someone edited my question and replace .Net 5 to .Net 6 i want to use ASP.NET 5